# Simple but powerful tool to create little diagrams on the Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, diagrams

All I need is a tool that allows to:

- create shapes: round, rectangle, or even rectangle with rounded corners
- insert text in these shapes
- connect these shapes with lines and/or arrows
- connections with lines/arrows should snap to the shape and be like "magnetic" to them when shape is moved around
- some coloring options like fill color, line color
- ability to change font globally for all shapes
- text boxes for little side notes to place anywhere

Nothing very fancy right? I find it very hard to find anything appropriate for the mac. I want something that is just simple for this kind of thing and not so overwhelmed with specializations that I don't care about, like all the heavy UML stuff and stuff for electronic engineers, architects, and so on. I just want these simple shapes and arrows. Got to make hundreds of simple Diagrams to represent hierarchies.

Maybe you can recommend a nice tool for the Mac that does just that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want [OmniGraffle](http://www.omnigroup.com/applications/OmniGraffle/).  It is designed to do exactly what you want.  It used to come with OS X, but hasn't since 10.3, I think.

Comment: +1 OmniGraffle is not only my favorite diagramming program, but one of my favorite programs period.

Comment: I know it. Hada demo, but find it pretty complex for my needs. I'm sure it's great but the learning curve is pretty big. At least it was for me so I decided to look for something else, more simple.

Comment: It seems to be one of those programs that either works the same way that your brain does and is a joy to use, or seems to be designed by an alien and is a constant fight.  I'm in the first group, but some of my coworkers are in the second.  I suggest giving it another try just to be sure.  There are a lot of features, but yu can ignore most of them for what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Another Registered User: Give it another try. Ignore the features you don't need (even close palettes you don't need); I suspect you'll pick it up faster than you think.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the OS X port of graphviz?

http://www.pixelglow.com/graphviz/

This works great if you've got some sort of data set that you're trying to visualize.

Answer (score 0):

I use [xmind](http://www.xmind.net) for that sort of thing. .

I doubt if you'll anything **really** simple that does all that you want, and I agree with those who recommend Omnigraffle.

Xmind though has a much better price, free. (and it's open source if that matters)

Answer (score 0):

I use OpenOffice.org for this kind of Graphics.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Pencil in Firefox.

http://www.evolus.vn/Pencil/

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use:
http://www.simplediagrams.com/

It is the least headachy for all my needs, and produces lovely output that is soft on the brain (check it out and see what I mean).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommmend [Lucidchart](http://www.lucidchart.com) which I have used for nearly 3 years now.  It's web-based so you can use it on any operating system and it has all the features you've described (and some other nice ones).